# Uniform distribution and ordered statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1,....,X_{n-1}$ be $(n-1)$ random variables following a Uniform distribution. If we note $X_{(1)},..,X_{(n-1)}$ the associated ordered statistics, I would like to prove that :
$$U_i=X_{(i+1)}-X_{(i)} $$
follows a uniform distribution. I would like to know if there's a simple demonstration of that fact or if anyone has pointers.

Comment: The $U_i$ do not follow uniform distributions, but their *joint* distribution is uniform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As detailed in (the simulation Bible) [Devroye's Non-uniform Variate Generation](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/Devroye_files/chapter_five.pdf) (1985), Chapter V, Section 2, the vector $(S_1,\ldots,S_{n})$ is ***jointly uniform***:

> **Theorem 2.1** $\quad$ If $U_{(1)}\le\cdots\le U_{(n)}$ are the Uniform $\mathcal U(0,1)$ order statistics of an $n$-sample, and the$$S_i=U_{(i)}-U_{(i-1)}\qquad(1\le i\le n+1)$$ where by convention $U_{(0)}=0$ and $U_{(n+1)}=1$, are the *uniform spacings*, then $(S_1,\ldots,S_{n})$ is uniformly distributed over the simplex
>   $$\mathcal A_{n-1}=\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_{n});\ 0\le x_i\,,\ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\le 1\right\}$$

*[The proof follows from the order statistics $U_{(1)}\le\cdots\le U_{(n)}$ being distributed as$$n!\,\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(u_{(i)})\times\mathbb{I}_{u_{(1)}\le\cdots\le u_{(n)}}$$$n!$ being the number of permutations of $\{1,...,n\}$ and from the change of variables from the $U_{(i)}$'s to the $S_i$'s being of Jacobian determinant equal to one]*
and

> **Theorem 2.2** $\quad$ The vector $$(S_1,\ldots,S_{n+1})$$ is distributed as
>   $$(\varepsilon_0,\ldots,\varepsilon_n)\Big/\sum_{i=0}^n\varepsilon_i$$where the $\epsilon_i$'s are iid $\mathcal E(1)$.

The above is also the constructive definition of a Dirichlet $$\mathcal D\overbrace{(1,\ldots,1)}^\text{$n+1$ terms}$$ distribution and the consequence is that $S_i$ is distributed as a Beta $\mathcal B(1,n)$ random variable. ***Not marginaly uniform*** then (if conditionally so).

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I don't quite get is the statement in the first theorem saying that the order statistics are uniform over the simplex. Why is it so ?

Comment: Do you mean you do not understand Devroye's proof (p.207)?

Comment: Yes, actually just the first line. Do you have some pointers for proving his statement?

Comment: Would it correct to say that,  according to theorem 2.2 and this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832712/understanding-the-flat-uniform-dirichlet-distribution-density-over-a-simplex, the joint distribution of (S_1,..., S_n+1) is the uniform distribution on the n simplex ?